# VPN Clients not able to resolve DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, pptp

I'm having trouble getting VPN clients to see other machines via hostname. IP addresses work fine, though this leads some systems to not working correctly.

I'm running Windows Server 2012 AD environment with a Netgear Prosafe router handling WAN in PPTP for offsite users.

Any computer on the main network has DNS, this is managed by windows server 2012 along with DHCP. The offsite PPTP clients are not picked up by the DNS though. The offsite computers are currently given DHCP by the Prosafe, which is where I think the issue lies.

Perhaps, would it be possible for Windows Server to handle the distribution of these VPN IP addresses? Adding the range into the pool don't seem to work with VPN client giving an error when trying to connect.

Comment: You know PPTP is horribly insecure, right?

Comment: I've used PPTP before with the same problem. I have had to set DNS manually on the VPN client. On Mac it's done in the Network Preferences under Advanced > DNS tab.

Comment: What DNS servers is the ProSafe configuring the VPN clients with? Itself, or the LAN DNS servers? When a VPN client is connected to the VPN, and you run an nslookup, what server does it use to look up the name? (ie your VPN LAN DNS server or the clients' pre-existing DNS server.

Comment: Update your question with the following information: What model Prosafe is it?  What firmware version?